# Keep google-chrome --headless always on

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, headless

I would like have

```
google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

always on 24/7 on my ubuntu server.
So far, when I close my ssh connection, it also closes the remote-debugging. 
I tried to run it through a php script as well, but without success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried launching it as `nohup google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222 & >/dev/null` so that it is immune to hangups and not owned by the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `nohup` to run your browser:

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

e.g.:

```
nohup google-chrome --headless --remote-debugging-port=9222
```